# Which ViewController method will be called when coming back from another application in objective c

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I am navigating user to youtube app on button click, i want to know which ViewController method will be called when he comes back to my app from youtube app.
In youtube app when user copies the url of the video,i want clipboard content to be pasted in a textfield automatically when user comes back to my app.

In which ViewController method, i should write the below code

```
 pasteVideoURL = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
 NSString *stringURL = pasteVideoURL.string;
 popUpTextField.text = stringURL;
```

I want to know OnResume method of android equivalent in objective-c.
I have tried using ViewWillAppear method but that's not getting called.

Comment: bascially i want equivalent of OnResume method in android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViewWillAppear will not get called in this case. You have to write your code in 
Application lifecycle methods which are

```
applicationWillEnterForeground

applicationDidBecomeActive
```

But I will suggest you to write code in `applicationWillEnterForeground`

You can use observer with this like :

In Your ViewController.m

Write following code in ViewDidLoad :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(setUpdateTextField:) name:@"UpdateTextField" object:nil];
```

Also implement this method :

```
-(void) setUpdateTextField:(NSNotification *) notification {
    pasteVideoURL = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
 NSString *stringURL = pasteVideoURL.string;
 popUpTextField.text = stringURL;
}
```

in AppDelegate.m

In `applicationWillEnterForeground`

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Your Code
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"UpdateTextField"object:nil];
}
```

This will surely help you.

Comment: you dont have to post a notification on applicationWillEnterForeground. You can register for UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification